# Can't make before_update filter working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, before-filter

I need to call method before update to check if PayPal details are correct.

I added in User.rb this:

```
 before_update :verify

 private
  def verify
  require 'httpclient'
  require 'xmlsimple'
  clnt = HTTPClient.new
    ....
      if account_status == "VERIFIED" 
        current_user.verified = "verified"
        current_user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Your account is verified"
      else 
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:error] = "Sorry, your account is not verified or you entered wrong credentials"
      end
    else
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:error] = "Your account is not verified or you entered wrong credentials"
    ...
end

end
```

**EDIT:Tried this:**

```
   class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

   before_filter :verify, :only => :update 
     def verify
          ...
     end
    end
```

but it isn't calling.

Maybe I should call if from here(**but I don't know how and where**) :

```
    class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

      def create
 build_resource

 if resource.save
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
    expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
    respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  redirect_to :back
  flash[:error] = "Your email has been already taken!"
 end
    end

      def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)

     params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
     params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?

    if resource.update_attributes(params[resource_name]) 
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
 else
       clean_up_passwords(resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :edit }
    end
  end
```

Can someone notice some errors in code ?

Comment: could we see the code that saves the user?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that it is Devise authentification.I added create action.

Comment: Create action creates and doesn't update. Maybe you're looking for `before_save` ?

Comment: I tried this `before_filter :verify, :only => :update 

    def verify ... end` not worked, but maybe I use it incorrectly

Comment: `before_filter` is for controller. and `before_update` is only for a model object that exists in db table. I agree with @apneadiving maybe `before_save`?

Comment: @mask8,@apneadiving can you suggest how to implement ?

Answer (score 0):

In User.rb, use `before_save` macro instead of before_update since before_update does not exist

One more thing, in your User model, `flash`is not accessible since it is only injectid in controller. You shout throw validation error instead or

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_save :verify

    private
    def verify(record)

      #... do checking ... and on error
      record.errors ... #is accesable, set your error here if you want to read it in controller 
       # rise here   error if you want
    end

end
```

More about activerecord callbacks

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: But it shouldn't be called when user CREATES his account,but only when updates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is right answer:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :verify, :only => :update 
  def verify
    ...
  end
end
```

Thanks for helping me